# CoreData syntax for inserting a new object

Tags: ios, core-data

Can someone tell me what is the difference between the two lines below? Don't they both create a new object that can be inserted? Thank you!

```
let author = Author(context: moc)
```

and

```
let author = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Author", into: self.moc!) as! Author
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines do exactly the same.

The first is just a more convenient, more generic and safer way

Comment: so means first one is useful compare to second one right ?